# Firebase OAuthProvider oidc (keycloak) invalid nonce

Tags: google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, keycloak

Here using keycloak to get idToken
Getting error when using signInWithCredential in firebase
Error

The nonce in ID Token "68963ae6-e032-42b4-a7b1-5672f053acf5" does not match the SHA256 hash of the raw nonce "68963ae6-e032-42b4-a7b1-5672f053acf5" in the request.

[image]

```
  const provider = new OAuthProvider('oidc.inspect-app');
  const auth = getAuth();
  const credential = provider.credential({idToken:orginApp.idToken, rawNonce: 
  orginApp.tokenParsed.nonce});
  signInWithCredential(auth, credential)
  .then((result:any) => {
           //code logic
  })
 })
```

Comment: You can try Casdoor: https://casdoor.org/ . It's an open-source IAM solution with full support of OIDC, LDAP and user management based on web UI. It supports the standard ID token format.

Answer (score 0):

I had to switch to code flow to make it work.

In this example i used ionic and OAuth2Client (Capacitor Plugin) to retrieve credentials after native signIn for ios and android.

```js
  public async signIn() {
    // Ionic Capacitor Plugin
    const result = await OAuth2Client.authenticate(OAUTH_OPTIONS);

    const provider = new OAuthProvider('oidc.your-keycloak-provider');

    provider.addScope('email');
    provider.addScope('profile');
    provider.addScope('openid');

    const credential = provider.credential({
      accessToken: result.access_token_response['access_token'],
      idToken: result.access_token_response['id_token']
    });

    return signInWithCredential(this.auth, credential);
  }
```